# Use which statement to fill certain rows

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
 df <- structure(list(Date = c("20-10-2014", "20-11-2014", "21-11-2014", 
 "22-10-2014", "23-10-2014", "24-10-2014", "25-10-2014", "26-10-2014"
 ), Team = c("Bulls", "Bulls", "Bulls", "Bulls", "Bulls", "Bulls", 
 "Bulls", "Bulls"), Result = c("W", "W", "W", "L", "L", "W", "W", 
 "L")), .Names = c("Date", "Team", "Result"), class = "data.frame",     row.names = c(NA, 
 -8L))
```

Of which I substract row with a "winning streak" of > 3 using this formula

```
which(rep(rle(df$Result)$lengths,rle(df$Result)$lengths)>2)
```

Now I would like to appoint the rows which fullfil the winningstreak criteria with a 1.

I know I can do:

```
 list <- which(rep(rle(df$Result)$lengths,rle(df$Result)$lengths)>2)
```

and then

```
 df <- df[list,]
```

to get the values but Im looking for one way to appoint 1 to the rows in list and 0 to others.

```
  df$point <- ifelse(df[list, ], "1", "0")
```

This doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `ifelse(rep(rle(df$Result)$lengths,rle(df$Result)$lengths)>2,1,0)`